# How can I write a bach file to relay a message across a LAN on boot?

Tags: lan, batch-file

What would a `.bat` file look like? in order to relay a message across a lan from `Computer A - 192.168.1.60` to `Server B - 192.168.1.7`, in which the Server communicates with the computer to prompt once its network is available (without any user requiring to login to `Server B`). I've been looking around on google for some solutions, but I haven't been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what messages you are trying to send, but you should check out the "net" command.

```
C:\> net help
```

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsNT/AdminTips/Network/NetCommands.html

All those command can be written in a batch file.

Also you may want to play with vbsrcipt, especially WMI object (Windows Management Instrumentation) on remote machines.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you have more info about what you're trying to do I may be able to be more specific.